# Table join results in NULL in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins, table, null

I'm trying to join a field named `"Area"` belonging to the shapefile 'Ancient Woodland' with the shapefile 'Net Development Area' (see screenshots below).

[image]

The results only return `NULL` which I don't understand because the field type of `"Area"` is a number. Even if I join the entire table to Development area all the entries return `NULL`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Both shapefiles have a common field which I'm using to perform the join (`"Substations"`). Surely I don't need to create a *.csvt* to do this?

Comment: Joins on floating-point values are nearly impossible due to representation issues. Just about any database primer will explain this.

Comment: Hi Vince, not sure what you mean by floating-point values

Comment: which fields are you using to make the join? if none of the columns are present it means the join failed

Comment: I'm using a field called Substations as a common field across both shapefiles. There are only 73 ancient woodland features versus the 408 features belonging to the Development Area shapefile. I've calculated areas of the dev areas and ancient woodland and named both fields "Area" (both shown at ID 48 in the screenshots above). I want to join Ancient Woodland's "Area" field to the development table. When doing so QGIS changes the field name to "Ancient Woldnad_Area" but all the entries are 'NULL'

Comment: My temporary solution in to save ancient woodlands as a CSV and perform the =VLOOKUP formula in excel with the Net Development Area CSV

Comment: You cannot join two area fields that way. You need to use the field "Substation" in both the two shapefiles in order to perform the join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table join doesn't work that way, you need to select two columns that contain the same text for features that you want to join.

So in your case you need to choose `Substations` in both Join and Target field.

Comment: Perfect iant, sorry for being ignorant!